# How to replace the column values from the dataframe into empty string if it matches completely with regex?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have to write a **clear on match** component. For that I was trying to use different spark built-in [functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#initcap-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-)

I have a switch statement for the different cases

```
val operator = operatorAndTokenTuple._1
val token = operatorAndTokenTuple._2
operator match {
  case "equals" => clearValueEquals(ds,token,columnsToBeUpdated)
  case "contains" =>clearValueContains(ds,token,columnsToBeUpdated)
  case "starts_with" => clearValueStartsWith(ds,token,columnsToBeUpdated)
  case "ends_with" => clearValueEndsWith(ds,token,columnsToBeUpdated)
  case "regex" => clearValueUsingRegex(ds,token,columnsToBeUpdated)
  case _ => throw new OperatorNotFoundException(s"${operatorAndTokenTuple._1} not applicable")
}
```

I have implemented every case except for `regex`. I have written a function like below

```
def clearValueUsingRegex(dataFrame: DataFrame,token :String,columnsToBeUpdated : List[String])= {
  columnsToBeUpdated.foldLeft(dataFrame) {
    (dataset ,columnName) =>
      dataset.withColumn(columnName,regexp_replace(col(columnName),token, ""))
  }
}
```

The problem with the above function is that it replaces the words that matches  the `regex` with that value. But, I am expecting a result which will only replace the cell value with an empty string only when the regex completely matched the cell value.

For example, if `token` is `.com` and my cell value is `google.com` it should not replace the `.com` from  the cell since cell value is `google.com`.

It should only replace when completely matches the values in the column cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not very far from the solution. I can suggest two ways to make it work.

#### UDF

Create a user defined function that takes the regular expression to match and the cell value:

```
private def replaceWithEmptyIfMatch(token: String) = udf((value: String) => {
  if (value.matches(token)) "" else value
})
```

And call it from `clearValueUsingRegex`:

```
... => 
dataset.withColumn(columnName, replaceWithEmptyIfMatch(token)(col(columnName)))
```

#### Column Expression

Use a slightly more complex expression on the column with matched values:

```
... => 
dataset.withColumn(columnName, 
                   when(length(regexp_extract(col(columnName), token, 0)) > 0, "")
                   .otherwise(col(columnName)))
```

Explanation: when the length of the very first group matched by `regexp_extract` is greater than 0 (so it was matched), then replace it with an empty string. Otherwise take the original column value.

Answer (score 0):

Use "^google.com$" if you want to match the whole string.